# What looks like a counting glitch in EE's reputation scores for August

Tags: support, bug, reputation, users-page

Looking at the August monthly reputation totals accumulated by users in EE, I see that Spehro Pefhany has a great total score of 3,768. However, his quarterly total (July, August, Sept 2016) is also 3,768. This looks like a counting glitch to me because clearly he has scored hundreds of reputation points in july 2016 by examination of his personal page.

[Link to reputation scores on EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users)

[Link to Spehro's reputation page showing reputation gained in July](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35530/spehro-pefhany?tab=reputation)

Comment: It is the other way around: the July reputation is added to August in the Monthly view. Already reported, but good to have more reports around to make future search easier, so you can leave this here and not delete it. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK great, glad I wasn't imagining things!